# What is Ajax and non-Ajax in PrimeFaces?

Tags: primefaces

I need to use PrimeFaces to create the front-end of a program, but I have no clue on how to do this (I'm doing an internship), can someone explain what the difference is between Ajax and non-Ajax?

Comment: Start by asking one of the people in the company you do your internship. If they use PrimeFaces, I'm 100% sure and convinced they can help you. Otherwise Google can too. https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_JavaScript_and_XML https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=web+development+ajax+vs+non-ajax

Comment: My tutor wasn't here for some time, thx for the help